# Revolution Slider - Advance once per mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel, revolution-slider

EDIT: Revolution Slider recently updated to Version 5 which by default supports mouse scrolling between slides without the need for additional javascript by the user and I've found it to work flawlessly.

***Original Question:***

I'm using a full screen Revolution Slider and by using the code found on the developers site I've managed to get the slides to advance using a mousewheel scroll.

The problem is that the slider is advancing more than one slide at a time depending on how much the user scrolls. I need the slide to only scroll once per mousewheel event. I tried using the solution found here but couldn't get it to work: [Removing event after one scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016323/removing-event-after-one-scroll)

I'm very new to Javascript so any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code I am currently using

```
(function() {

 var slider = revapi1;

 slider.parent().on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {

 if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {

 slider.revprev();

 }
 else {

 slider.revnext();

 }

 });

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

`revprev()` and `revnext()` is where moves happen.

Deeper you should find something like *speed*, *steps_length*...